# Data.table in R into datatable in Python translation problem (normalization)

Tags: python, r, data.table, py-datatable

I have this code in `R` where I am using `data.table`, and I have the intention to translate it into `Python` with `datatable`. It creates columns with the value of each existing column divided by the mean of the total. Kind of normalization.

```
dataset[ , paste0( cols, suffix) := lapply( .SD,  function(x){ x/mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)} ), 
         by= col_A, 
         .SDcols= cols]
```

Comment: You might also find this useful https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/comparison_with_rdatatable.html#modify-several-columns-and-keep-others-unchanged

Comment: this page may be useful for column assignment : https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/transform_data.html#column-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datatable import f,by,update,dt

dataset=dt.Frame({'col_A':[0,0,1,1], 'col_B':[1,2,3,4], 'col_C':[5,6,7,8]})
cols = dataset[:,[int,float]].names
dataset[:, update(**{col+'_norm': f[col]/dt.mean(f[col]) for col in cols if col!='col_A'}), by(f.col_A)]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, `update` function and `del` operator operate in-place.  This may be done in a loop also if there are many columns

```
DT[:, update(y_suffix = f.y/dt.mean(f.y), v_suffix = f.v/dt.mean(f.v)), by("x")]
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
from datatable import dt, f, g, by, update

DT = dt.Frame(x = ["b"]*3 + ["a"]*3 + ["c"]*3,
              y = [1, 3, 6] * 3,
              v = range(1, 10))
```